# Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, apk, mobile-application

My android application using Kotlin is throwing this exception when I try to Run 'app' in the emulator o in my cellphone. When I build my project it runs well, with no errors.

I am using:

- SDK 28 (Android 9.0 (Pie))
- Gradle 5.1.1
- Gradle Plugin 3.5.0-alpha03
- Kotlin 1.3.10
- Java 1.8.0_151
- OSX 10.13.2

```
    org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: buildOutput.apkData must not be null
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:194)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildOutput.apkData must not be null
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.EarlySyncBuildOutput$Companion$load$2.invoke(EarlySyncBuildOutput.kt:103)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.EarlySyncBuildOutput$Companion$load$2.invoke(EarlySyncBuildOutput.kt:67)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:174)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:691)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:721)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:712)
        ...
```

Comment: I created a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129994596

Comment: I have the same after I updated Android Studio to 3.4

Comment: Check Lemberg answer that works for me, I've faced that issue today

Comment: Same for Java (not necessary Kotlin) after installing Android Studio 3.5.

Answer (score 327):

Click `Build` -> `Clean Project`

Then `Build` -> `Make Project`

Tested on gradle 3.5.0-alpha3, -alpha5 and 3.4.0 (project gradle)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: I can confirm this is working as well with the version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha05` (with `Build` -> `Rebuild Project` in AS)

Comment: Also works for `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-rc02'`

Comment: Sadly it requires upgrading to Android Studio 3.5, I can't tell my team to switch to an unstable channel for Android Studio updates.

Comment: @void.pointer why not? I'm on canary (also for production) for years. Can't complain about stability or bad performance (using macOS)..

Comment: Works on Android Studio 3.4

Comment: trying on AndroidStudio3.5 on Mac OS, all sdk updated, using gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`, this solution is not working for me

Comment: @MihodiHasanLushan Delete the `build` folder and build project again. Otherwise check if your gradle is correct (sdk, dependencies, etc). Are you sure you are getting the same error message?

Comment: tried those, yes, I am getting this error. @MartinPfeffer

Comment: @MihodiHasanLushan for me it works only after i'ved run 'gradlew clean build' on android studio's terminal. i am using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` with android studio 3.5 on windows10

Comment: Works on Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: I only had to clean since my gradle version was 3.5.1 when I updated my project fro my repo.

Comment: Also works for `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'` Android Studio 3.6.3

Answer (score 165):

> **FOR Android Studio 3.5 | 3.6**

debug builds finish without any error. Creating a signed .apk leads to the same error

```
buildOutput.apkData must not be null
```

the Simple solution that I found is. During the signing of the apk after entering the signing credentials when you navigate to the next screen then it will ask for the destination folder just change the default path.

Let's assume the current destination path is

> c:\user\folder\project\app

change it to

> c:\user\folder\project\

then it will generate the signed apk successfully.

[image: Android studio destination folder screenshot]

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. Thanks. This is just simple and just really stupid build error of Android Studio.

Comment: Wow, you saved my life with this. However is this a bug in Android Studio or is my project messed up?

Comment: @ Vijay Kumar Kanta this is an issue with the studio I hope in the new update it will be fixed

Comment: OMG, this Android Studio upgrade to 3.5 brings a lot of issues for me.

Comment: Very useful in Android 3.5.2

Comment: Thanks & Nice solution. I updated Android Studio even this error occurs in Android Studio 3.6. This solution saved my day. Thanks again

Comment: thanks for the solution my app has hundred to thousand c++ class so cleaning will consume time.

Answer (score 162):

> **For Android Studio 3.5 & 3.6 Update (APK signed issue)**

**Step 1:** I have resolved this issue by modifying the **Destination Folder** location.

Before

```
c:\user\folder\project\app
```

After

```
c:\user\folder\project\apk
```

[image]

> **For Android Studio `3.4` Update.**

**Step 1:** After update **Android Studio 3.4** you need to add all the dependency that used in your module or library in your app-level `build.gradle`.

**Step 2:** Clean Project(Build > Clean Project)

**Step 3:** Rebuild Project(Build > Rebuild Project)

Now, Your Project will compile Perfectly.

Comment: what's that? what should I do exactly? > Step 1: After update Android Studio 3.4 you need to add all the dependency that used in your module or library in your app-level build.gradle.

Comment: @babay Suppose you are using any library that is using Glide library. Then you have to add your Glide dependency in your App level build.gradle also.

Comment: i got this error after step 3.  APT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

Comment: @james I think there is a resource missing.

follow the below steps to find an issue.

Click on Gradle(You will find in Top-Right Corner) > app_name(root) > other > assembleDebug

Comment: @VishrutMavani Thank for your answer, but i found the really stupid error of Android studio. I just changed the build output path. That is. Solution by Shuham Jain. See below his solution.

Comment: 'Destination Folder' is a field in Generate Signed Bundle or APK modal;

Comment: This fixed my issue in Android Studio v3.5 and a Java project. This is a pretty standard occurrence whenever building Android apps now ... (1) get a weird incomprehensible build error (2) google it (3) stack overflow (4) apply seemingly unrelated workaround in a specific order (5) pray (6) it works (7) go to step (1)

Comment: I can't believe the working solution to this problem is actually "Change the destination folder." But it is! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i do not know where is suppossed to change that directory. I have not figured out yet

Comment: @Billyjoker During the signing APK after Entering the signing credentials when you navigate to the next screen then it will ask for the destination folder. just change the default path.

Comment: Within 3.5.3, 'Change the destination folder' not supporting due to studio already disabled the change option of destination

Comment: @NuwanWithanage I have another solution & it may help you. try to generate debug signed build first then generate release signed.

Answer (score 53):

I was getting this error also, when trying to "Generate Signed APK" for my release version.
I tried all of the above methods, unfortunately none worked for me.

What worked, was generating first the debug signed version of the app, and then generating again the release one.

I do not know what exactly changed or what the original problem was, but it worked. I hope it will help you too, because this error is quite annoying...

Comment: In my case I need to generate first product flavor apk (debug to release) to last flavor (debug to release).

Comment: Yes!! It worked for me too. thanks. 
I don't know why but it looks like a bug.

Comment: trying on AndroidStudio3.5 on Mac OS, all sdk updated, using gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`, this solution is not working for me

Comment: In my case: AndroidStudio3.5, Build bundle(s)/apk(s) => Build apk(s), then Generate Signed APK

Comment: It is crazy, but this solution works - I don't understand why.
Android Studio 3.5, Windows

Comment: Its a bug in Android Studio 3..5

Answer (score 23):

Cleaning the project didn't help me but manually deleting all the auto-generated **build** folders in all modules helped.
[image]

Comment: This is the equivalent of cleaning the project.

Comment: No, it isn't, try to clean project from Android Studio and then check App directory for `build` directories in any file explorer, you will see that some files are still left there.

Comment: In my case I had multiple flavours, it worked once I had deleted all the build folder along with Flavour specific folders. 
After deleting folders, I had to close the project and reopen to get it working

Comment: trying on AndroidStudio3.5 on Mac OS, all sdk updated, using gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`, this solution is not working for me

Answer (score 18):

**Updating to Android Studio 3.4.?**, i get the message

> Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null

looking for an answer i found the procedure:

`Build` -> `Clean Project`

but it doesn´t worked, i know that this procedure will delete the content into the `/build` directory but for my experience it doesn´t work in all cases, so i tried the "raw" way, deleting the directory:

```
/app/build/
```

then i rebuild the project and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to also remove all `<flavor>/<buildConfig>` directories (it's about `output.json` files in them). `Clean project` alone didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

All the solutions didn't work with me

**Android Studio V 3.5**

**Android gradle plugin V 3.4.2**

**Gradle Version V 5.1.1**

1. Clean the project
2. Restart Android Studio + Invalidate Caches
3. Delete the build, debug, and releases folder
4. Make project
5. Generate signed APK

[Reference](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129994596#comment28)

Answer (score 9):

I tried above multiple solutions but nothing has happened then I found this
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646388/android-studio-3-5-cause-buildoutput-apkdata-must-not-be-null-clean-rebuild-a#answer-57823344) and worked for me

```
    deleting debug/output.json and release/output.json solved my problem
```

Now I am able to generate apk

Answer (score 7):

I've tried many things to solve the issue, but nothing helped. I get this error when trying to generate a signed apk.

Downgrading to older versions of Android Studio helped (3.4.2) worked, however this is not the solution.

The 'Clean Project' function in AS does not clean the place where your generated apk is created and there is one file that may be blocking the whole procedure: output.json

Try removing output.json from .../app/projectname/release/output.json

Answer (score 5):

I was using Android Studio 3.5 beta 2 and I was having the exact same error but only on my release build. After trying every other solution I found, the only way I was able to compile again was to go back to Android Studio 3.4.

Comment: This "solution" also worked for me. Downgrade to AS 3.4.2, downloadhere: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and changing from 3.5.0 to: 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

1. delete build folder from your project manually.
2. in terminal of android studio type this command

if windows user

```
gradlew clean build
```

if linux user

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: trying on AndroidStudio3.5 on Mac OS, all sdk updated, using gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`, this solution is not working for me

Answer (score 4):

This issue is happens usually when you are running multiple android studio window with different projects.

The solution is

- choose project than delete .gradle and build folders
- than clean and rebuild the project.

please ref screen shot attached

[image: please ref screen shot attached]

Comment: trying on AndroidStudio3.5 on Mac OS, all sdk updated, using gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`, this solution is not working for me

Comment: Can you try File > Invalidate caches/Restart after delete auto-generated files .gradle and build @MihodiHasanLushan

Answer (score 4):

Just change the **Apk release/debug location**.

EX:

```
/home/sanaebadi/Desktop
```

after change :

```
/home/sanaebadi/apk
```

Answer (score 3):

the only solution that works for me is using in my root gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

what i've tried : 
- clear all build folder manually 
- invalidate cache
but none of these is work

PS: i'm using android studio 3.5 btw

Update :

just like @Vishrut Mavani, changing the destination folder of your release version is work

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to delete all files and folders from the apk output folder.
I had this problem when creating a signed apk for a "production" flavor and the `output.json` in the "feature" output folder causes the problem -> `Android Studio 3.6 Canary 7` showed me the correct error message.
It is also working now for AS 3.5 stable with Gradle Plugin 3.5.0.

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions didn't work with me
In my case from AndroidStudio 3.4+ update to 3.5.
And finally I solve it by modify 'Destination Folder' to  "app/build/outputs/apk"
[detail pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmaCT.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The solution :-

1- `Build -> Clean Project` didn't help

2-`Build -> Make Project` didn't help

3- restart android studio didn't help

4- Manually remove Build folder from `app` and `project` didn't help

the only solution for me was to remove all old builds from destination folder

Answer (score 2):

Manually delete all the exiting build variant folder as well build folder in project folder worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this issue happen on updating android Studio V3.4 to V3.5. 
Try to delete `debug/output.json` and `release/output.json` files.

Then Try these steps:

**Step 1:** Clean Project(Build > Clean Project)

**Step 2:** Rebuild Project(Build > Rebuild Project)

Answer (score 2):

I have android studio 3.5.1 . For me below steps are worked

1. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
2. After android studio restarted click on Build -> Clean project
3. Then Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

In my case build and launch project with different build configs was successful. But generating signed apk throws error `Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null` on the other hand apk was generated and Build Output toggle view prints `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. Manual installation ends with message `App not installed`. My fault was using `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'` and after changing to `compileSdkVersion 28` all goes well.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried **all solutions** and non of them helped! finally after many trying, I figured it out, just follow the tips:

1. copy your signature keystrok (that you use to release) inside `yourProject/app/`
2. **gradle.properties** (modify values related to your own key):

   ```
   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=KEYSTROK_NAME
   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=KEY_ALIAS
   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=R_PASS
   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=K_PASS
   android.enableR8=true
   ```
3. app level **build.gradle** (inside android):

   ```
   signingConfigs{
       release{
           if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
               storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
               storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
               keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
               keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
           }
       }
   }

   configurations {
       cleanedAnnotations
       compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
   }
   ```
4. app level **build.gradle** (inside buildTypes):

   ```
   release {
       manifestPlaceholders = [analytics_deactivated: "false"]
       minifyEnabled true
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       useProguard true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
   ```

   ### 5. finally this command:

mac: `./gradlew clean assemble_YOUR_FAVOR_Release`

win: `gradlew clean assemble_YOUR_FAVOR_Release`

where `_YOUR_FAVOR_` is your optional favor, if you are not using any favor, just simply use `assembleRelease` instead of `assemble_YOUR_FAVOR_Release`

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens after update my Android studio v3.4 to v3.5 
Now, it is working fine

I fixed this issue by deleting debug/output.json and release/output.json files

Android Studio 3.5
compilesdkVersion 28

apk generating working

Answer (score 1):

I was also annoyed by the same bug. But changing my **Signed apk destination** from **c/users/project/app** to **c/users/project** worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1- Delete all generated app bundles (.aab) and APKs for all variants.

2- Delete the build folder

3- clean project

Answer (score 1):

Generate Signed APK for **debug**,
and then you can generate signed APK for **release**.

Comment: You can't generate "Signed debug APK"

Comment: You can sign your debug build https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode

Answer (score 0):

Seems cleaning the project may resolve the issue, but for me it worked like this.

> *File->sync project with gradle files.*

Answer (score 0):

**AS 4.0.1 (installed via snap)**

**Ubuntu 18.04 lts**

configuring builds via build variant.

Combinations of invalidate cache / build /  clean etc didnt help on their own, the only thing that helped was to switch build the active build variant back to `armDebug` and clean / rebuild after that.

[image]

Once I switched back to the desired variant I could build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`If your using different build variants, Select the specific folder to generate signin apk file. When you are trying to generate signin apk flow, you can change the path. For me, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the path was pointing to e: drive and other solutions didn't work for me.
I did:

1. Change the path
2. The path must be in the `c:` drive

It solved the problem