# Android Studio 3.5 Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null Clean & Rebuild already tried

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After I've updated Android Studio 3.4 to 3.5 and wanted to build a Signed APK, however I get the error :

> Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null Error

I've already tried to Clean & Make the Project and to Clean & Rebuild the Project, with no success.

I am using Android Gradle 3.5.0 & Gradle Version 5.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503325/cause-buildoutput-apkdata-must-not-be-null)

Comment: Thank you, for your comment. However, as you can see in my post, I've  already checked the Clean & Rebuild Fix

Comment: I have added there another solution, which helped me today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670979/264750

Comment: Please refer to this link **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503325/cause-buildoutput-apkdata-must-not-be-null/59191126#59191126**

Answer (score 20):

This issue happens after update my Android studio v3.4 to v3.5 
Now, it is working fine

```
I fixed this issue by deleting debug/output.json and release/output.json files
otherwise change your apk destination folder path.

Android Studio 3.5
compilesdkVersion 28

apk generating working
```

Answer (score 3):

option 1 - change the destination folder of the apk generated and generate apk again.

option 2 - delete the output.json file under release folder and generate apk again.

It solved my problem. I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Manually delete the build directory and rebuild, That worked for me

Comment: That's what 3dmg suggested, as well. I will try it out next week.

Comment: Make sure you delete all the build folders - i didn't delete the app/build folder. Worked when i did (i also deleted the debug and release folders as well)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why the issue was occurring but changing the

> destination folder of output apk

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on AS 3.4.2 version. I've tried everything (Clean & Make the Project and to Clean & Rebuild) and downgraded to 3.4.2 at last.

This issue might be fixed in the 3.6 release.
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/07/android-studio-36-canary-5-available.html

Comment: Same for me, downgraded to 3.4.2 yesterday evening. However, thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

Delete the contents of the build folders (existing *.apk and output.json):-

1. AndroidProject\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\debug\
2. AndroidProject\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\
3. AndroidProject\app\release\

And then rebuild the system by:-

File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files