# Gradle error 'variant.getMergeResources()' on Android Studio 3.5.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I use Android Studio 3.5.0 and Gradle version 5.6.1, 5.6, 5.4.1, but still get the same results:

```
INFO: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
```

all of my gradle file included in here

https://gist.github.com/derohimat/b7832dc4973a125c289c804998519518

Comment: share your gradle file..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused from gms services 4.3.1. So i had to change it to:

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
```

I have found this by running:

```
gradlew sync -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

in terminal. Go to view -> tool windows -> Terminal in Android Studio.

Hope your problem will solve

Comment: I try downgrade `google-services to 4.2.0` but still get error

Comment: the error changes to `Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null`

Comment: yes, I already see that and solved by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698879/898404

Answer (score 0):

> INFO: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.

**First of all**, this is only a normal information that tells you about the API deprecation, which is a usual deprecation process over several Gradle major releases. So, no much worry about it.

**Secondly**, as of Gradle 5.1, it is recommended that the configuration avoidance APIs be used whenever tasks are created by custom plugins. See [Task Configuration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html).

**Thirdly**, your own gradle build script looks not including any statements about `variant.getMergeResources()`, but this doesn't mean that **your gradle plugins applied** also don't include reference to `variant.getMergeResources`, so you need to look into all of your plugins, e.g.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Probably above plugin implementation have at least one reference to the `variant` object.

### **Edit #1**

Run below command to get the detailed build information about your project:

```
./gradlew build --scan
```

For example, you will see something like below

[image]

More about build troubleshooting can be found at 
[Gradle Build Troubleshooting](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:task_configuration_avoidance_troubleshooting)

Comment: I comment this plugins


`//        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.20.0'`


and downgrade `google-services to 4.2.0`


but getting error `Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null`