# When I generate an android app bundle it fails with "buildOutput.apkInfo must not be null"

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio completes the building process then says that build failed

"I have tried cleaning the project & rebuilding it but it ends up with the same result"

output:

```
buildOutput.apkInfo must not be null
```

EDIT: I figured my problem here and it seems like some how my package changed and I fixed it with reversing the changes.

If you came here to solve a similar problem check this link first [Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503325/cause-buildoutput-apkdata-must-not-be-null[1])

Comment: [Has this helped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503325/cause-buildoutput-apkdata-must-not-be-null)

Comment: @TaseerAhmad no didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **For Android Studio 3.5 Update. (APK signed issue)**

I had the same issue. I have resolved this issue by modifying the **Destination Folder**.

> **Step by step**

1. Build
2. Generate signed Bundle/APK
3. Select Android App Bundle or APK
4. Add Keystore
5. On Destination Folder: Change `c:\user\folder\project\app` to `c:\user\folder\project\`

> **Summary**

Before

```
c:\user\folder\project\app
```

After

```
c:\user\folder\project\
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just simple steps started to work:

1. Delete the build folder of App and inner Modules.
2. Clean Project.
3. Rebuild Project.

That's it.